# Prevent children div from breaking out of the CCS-Card

Tags: html, css, card

### I want to create a CSS-Card

On the left side should be a image and on the ride side a headline and paragraph.

Furthermore, in the lower section of the right side there should be a profile picture, name and date of the post.

---

**So my question is**

How can I prevent the content in the **container-article** from overlapping the **container-card**?

[My Current State with the CSS-Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8sXa.png)

----------

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

    <meta name="author" content="Ufuk Can Varol" />
    <meta name="description" content="Article Card v3" />
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />
    <!-- Font-Family [Manrope]-->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope:wght@500;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link
      rel="shortcut icon"
      type="image/png"
      href="assets/images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />

    <title>Article</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="container-card">
        <div class="container-image"></div>
        <div class="container-article">
          <div class="article-header">
            <h2>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Voluptatum, officia.
            </h2>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum,
              vel suscipit impedit accusantium nihil minima asperiores,
              exercitationem sapiente ad expedita fugiat. Veritatis sit
              voluptatem qui est unde, aspernatur nemo impedit!
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="article-footer">
            <div class="article-footer-author">
              <div class="author-image"></div>
              <p>
                Savannah Garrett <br />
                28 Jun 2020
              </p>
            </div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**CSS**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

#container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;

  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.container-card {
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.container-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  background-color: azure;
}

.container-article {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.article-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.article-footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height: 300px` from `.container-card`. If you set a fixed height it won't expand to fit its child elements.

Comment: I don't want the div container-card to adapt to its content 
but rather I'm looking for a way to prevend
the content from overlapping the div container-card

Comment: So you want the content to shrink?

Comment: Yes I want the Content within the div container-card to shrink instead of breaking out

Comment: You can reduce the size of the contents, i.e. `font-size`, `margin`, to make it fit. But, as `.container-card` has a fixed height and width, it's contents won't shrink.

Comment: Is there no way that forces the content to shrink to fit?

Comment: Either media-queries or JS

Comment: @moon You can declare [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) (with a value of `auto`, `hidden` or `scroll`) on either `.container-card` or `.container-article` so the containing block doesn't expand and instead either clips or scrolls its contents.